# instantiate object from Webservice

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to instantiate an object from a  Webservice, then call my method and pass it the HttpContext of the current page.

It wont allow me to pass the HttpContext

Why?  thanks

```
''''''''''''''''''service

    Imports System.Web
    Imports System.Web.Services
    Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols

    <WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
    <WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
    <Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
    Public Class WebService
         Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

        <WebMethod()> _
        Public Sub doThis(ByVal HC As HttpContext)

            'do something

        End Sub

    End Class


''''''''''''''''''page
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim s As test2.WebService = New test2.WebService

        s.doThis(HttpContext.Current)



    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: So you getting error yes? If so please add error message to question

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to pass an `HttpContext` object into the web service proxy method, but the web service proxy is not asking for an `HttpContext` object, so it is probably telling you that it's a type mismatch.

When you ask for a complex data type as an argument in a web service call, or you return a complex data type from a web service call, you have to remember that it converts that into a SOAP message in XML.  When you add a reference to a web service on the client-side, it creates new custom classes for all those complex types.  When you add a web service reference, Visual Studio creates what are called proxy classes.  They are classes that match the public interface of the web service.  However, each new web service reference creates a whole new set of proxy classes which are entirely separate data types.  These proxy classes are named the same thing as the original types, but they are placed in a separate namespace named after the web service reference name.

Therefore, on the client-side, it's not really a `HttpContext` object that it's requesting.  In reality, it's asking for a custom type that has the same properties as the `HttpContext` class.  So, either you need to make a new object of the correct type and then copy the properties from one to the other, or you need to change the type being requested by the web service.  For instance:

```
Dim s As test2.WebService = New test2.WebService
Dim r As test2.HttpContext = New test2.HttpContext
' Populate r's properties with the values from HttpContext.Current
s.doThis(r)
```

Comment: wow thanks for the great detaile answer - are you saying that I should try this --  
dim r as object = HttpContext.Current 

s.doThis(r)